# Does reviews must be assigned to special users?

Tags: discussion, feature-request, review-queues

I'm talking about reviews in general whatever the review type it is, I think it must be assigned to the users as per their specializations, for example, the user must has a score of 10 in Android in order to review Android questions, as when I review questions I fall in the trap of giving a wrong review according to not fully understanding the reviewed specialization, I know I can skip, but sometimes with a question [like this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36421224/does-jquery-support-css4-selectors), you can say with a complete confidence it's a **"too broad"** or **"primarily opinion-based"** one, but after my review, baaaaang *it was a test and you failed, it's a pretty good question, you have to take care about how you review posts*.

Comment: Reviewers take filters as they like it.

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ It is the first time I know about that. But I think it must be considered that the user must has a sufficient tag score to be able to review it.

Comment: Is this a [tag:feature-request] actually?

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ I think yes

Comment: @gnat What in the world does that question have to do with this one? Perhaps this question is slightly unclear, but Shog9 giving a history of moderation tools does not seem to be similar to reviewing based on tag specializations...

Comment: I'm not sure what value there is in editing a four-year-old, heavily-downvoted post, to fix a single grammatical error in the title while leaving several other grammatical errors intact.

Comment: @F1Krazy no value

Comment: @MuhammedRefaat Then why do it?

Comment: @F1Krazy I feel itshy about errors in the title, and anyway the ques. can't be deleted

Answer (score 10, accepted):

If we restricted reviews only to those with score 10 in a tag

- there would be nobody who could review new tags
- some existing tags would also have no reviewers e.g. [cartesian-coordinates](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/cartesian-coordinates) which currently has a [top answer score of 7](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/cartesian-coordinates/topusers)

If you don't understand a question in review, skip is always a valid option.